# How to fix this regex pattern?

Tags: javascript

I have this regex pattern `^(\/([a-z]+)?-?([a-z]+)?)+$` I am testing it in https://regex101.com/r/Se3e70/1/. The pattern it accepts are

- /abc
- /abc-def
- /
- /abc/abc
- /abc/abc-def

but the problem is it also accepts

1. /-
2. /abc-

which I do not want.

How can I make sure to avoid these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
[
'/abc',
'/abc-def',
'/',
'/a',
'/abc/abc',
'/abc/abc-def',
'/-',
'/abc-',
].forEach(str => 
console.log(
/^(\/(([a-z]+)+(-[a-z]+)?)?)+$/.test(str)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want: some groups joined with `-`, but ending by the group without `-`

```
^(\/([a-z]+-?)*([a-z]+))+$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^\/(([a-z]+)([-/][a-z]+)*)?$
```

I think this should work for you.

```
^\/
```

This part makes sure you have a string starting with a forward slash.

```
([a-z]+)
```

After the slash only letters from a to z are allowed.

```
([-/][a-z]+)*
```

This part makes sure that if there is a dash or slash it is followed by letters (which prevents e.g. /abc-). The star in the end ensures that /abc works but allows you to add multiple slash dash letter combinations.

```
(([a-z]+)([-/][a-z]+)*)?
```

The whole part is wrapped with a ? to make sure / also works.
In theory you could add some none-capturing group markers (:?) to this if you do not need to actually know whats between the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
'/abc',
'/abc-def',
'/',
'/abc/abc',
'/abc/abc-def',
'/-',
'/abc-','/a'
].forEach(str => 
console.log(
/^(\/([a-z\-]+[a-z]+)?([a-z]+)?)+$/.test(str)))
```